# Property of Homology and orientation

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Show that the isomorphism type of homology groups does not depend on the orientations of simplical complex.
  I need help!!

Comment: Orientation doesn't come up at all in the definition of homology... What kind of homology anyway? Singular, cellular, simplicial...?

Comment: Simplical, I think. It comes from simplical complex in a lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that simplices with different orientations are homotopically-equivalent to each other, i.e., orientation does not affect homotopy type.